# ¿Cómo mostrar mensaje de "ECHO" en el mismo formulario form?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hola buenos días a todos, espero puedan aclararme una duda, actualmente tengo el siguiente formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver cada uno de esos checkbox tiene un determinado valor y un STOCK (en mi BD), entonces cuando se de click en el botón "ENTREGAR", los items que ya no tengan STOCK, me muestre un aviso en el mismo formulario que para ese item en especifico no hay STOCK, pero el resto si se entregaron correctamente.  Y claro que se genere un reporte y se agregue a una tabla nueva (eso ya lo tengo también), pero lo que no logro es el "ECHO" en el mismo formulario indicándome que ya no hay STOCK para ese uniforme, actualmente mi método entregar es el siguiente:

```
<?php  
if (!isset($_POST['oculto'])) {
    exit();
}

include 'conexion.php';
$dni = $_POST['txt-dni'];
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
$fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
```

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/

```
foreach ($checkbox as $seleccion) // PARA CADA CHECKBOX 'UNIFORME ' SELECCIONADO
{

    $query = ("SELECT * FROM tabla_uniformes WHERE id_uniforme=" .$seleccion);
    $consulta=$bd->query($query);
                                        
        while ($fila=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $stock= $fila['stock'];  // LLAMO EL STOCK ACTUAL DE UNIFORME SELECCIONADO
            $descripcion= $fila['descripcion']; // LLAMO TAMBIEN EL NOMBRE DEL UNIFORME
            $newstock = $stock - 1 ;  //RESTO AL STOCK 1 UNIDAD
            //print($resultado);

                if ( $newstock >= 0)  //VERIFICAMOS SI AL RESTARLE 1 AUN QUEDA O NO STOCK, SI ES NEGATIVO EL STOCK ESTA EN '0'
                {
                  /*------------------------------------------------------------*/                          
                    $sentencia = $bd->prepare("UPDATE tabla_uniformes SET stock = ? WHERE id_uniforme = ?;");
                    $resultado1 = $sentencia->execute([$newstock,$seleccion]);  //ACTUALIZAMOS EL NUEVO STOCK EN LA TABLA UNIFORMES
                                                
                    if ($resultado1 === TRUE) { // SI TODO FUE CORRECTO AGREGO LOS DATOS DE LA PERSONA A LA TABLA ENTREGAS
                                                            
                        $sentencia = $bd->prepare("INSERT INTO tabla_entregas(dni,descripcion,fecha) VALUES (?,?,?);");
                        $resultado2 = $sentencia->execute([$dni,$descripcion,$fecha]);} // AGREGAMOS A LA TABLA DE ENTREGAS 
                                                
                    if ($resultado2 === TRUE) {
                    
                    header("location:../vistas/m-entregar.php"); // SI TODO FUE CORRECTO REGRESAMOS A LA PESTAÑA DE ENTREGAR
                                    
                    }else{
                        echo "Error";   } // ERROR

                    

                /*------------------------------------------------------------*/
                }else{
                
                    //ACA MUESTRO UN MENSAJE DE ALERTA QUE NO HAY STOCK, PERO SOLO FUNCIONA CUNAOD LOS ITEMS
                    //SELECCIONADOS NO TIENE STOCK, BASTA CON QUE ELIGA UNO QUE SI TIENE STOCK YA NO ME MUESTRA ESTE MENSAJE.

                      echo "<script>  
                            alert('No hay stock suficiente');
                            window.location= '../vistas/m-entregar.php'
                            </script>";
                    

                }
                        
        }

}
```

Cuando elijo, por ejemplo 2 uniformes que ya no tienen stock, me muestra la alerta que no se tiene stock para cada uno, pero..... si aparte de esos 2 uniformes que no tiene stock elijo 1 que SI TIENE STOCK, ya no me muestra la alert y ejecuta todo el procedo de restar y agregar a la tabla entregas.
Espero me puedan ayudar saludos.

Comment: Los datosblos mandas con javascript o normal con el formulario en su atributo ```action```

Comment: Mi pregunta es, ¿por qué permites la selección si no tienen stock? ¿Por qué no deshabilitas la posibilidad de elegir items agotados? En un escenario cualquiera eso sería lo que ocurriría, permitir una selección para luego decir al usuario que no hay revela un error de diseño que conduce a una mala UX...

Comment: @christian, si los datos los envio por el POST

Comment: @A.Cedano, interesante aclaración, veré la manera de cargar en los CHECKBOX solo los uniformes que tenga stock.

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo un panorama un poco mas claro. Espero me puedan ayudar en cargar solamente los uniformes que tengan  stock. Este es mi método que carga los uniformes en los checkbox y los envia por un echo en HTML.

```
<?php  
$id = $_GET['id'];//recibo el ID del área seleccionada     
include("../includes/conexion.php");                    
    
$query = $bd->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabla_uniformes WHERE area_id =".$id);                   
$query->execute();
$data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$html="";
//print json_encode($data);
foreach ($data as $value)
$html.='<li> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"" value="'.$value["id_uniforme"].'" id="'.$value["id_uniforme"].'"> <label for="'.$value["id_uniforme"].'">'.$value["descripcion"].'</label> </li>';
echo $html;   //imprimo cada uniforme del area en forma de CHECKBOX y lo devuelvo ?>
```

Esta es mi tabla de uniformes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y asi es como lo muestro actualmente, pero quiero que solo se muestren los que tienen STOCK.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta a tu problema, es preferible que edites tu pregunta

Comment: Si quieres que solo se muestren lo saque tienen stock hazlo con un __where__ en tu consulta  ```where stock>0 ``` o ```where stock !=0```